# RegEx R: match strings with same character exact number of times anywhere in string

Tags: r, regex

I guess this is straight forward but I can't manage to get my RegEx right and haven't found an exact example yet...

How can I match only strings with a specific character an exact number of times (not necessarily repeating!)

Let's look at a data set

```
terms<-c('breeding'
    ,'foraging'
    ,'prey'
    ,'breeding_season'
    ,'foraging_time'
    ,'seabird_ecology'
    ,'annual_reproductive_success'
    ,'sea_surface_temperature'
    ,'mean_chick_weight')
```

I want to select all strings that have ***exactly*** two underscores ('_')

I can try:

```
stringr::str_detect(terms, "_{2}")
```

no luck

```
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Or

```
terms[stringr::str_detect(terms, "._.{2,}")]
```

gives

```
[1] "breeding_season"             "foraging_time"               "seabird_ecology"            
[4] "annual_reproductive_success" "sea_surface_temperature"     "mean_chick_weight"
```

but I want only

```
[1] "annual_reproductive_success" "sea_surface_temperature"     "mean_chick_weight"
```

Thank you RegEx masters

Comment: Try `str_count` instead of `str_detect`  - `str_count(terms, "_")`

Comment: I'm guessing from context that you do NOT really want to accept any of `"__"`, `"__word"`, `"_word_"` or `"word__"`. But if you do want to flag all of them, the task is much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're missing is the negated character class.  You want to match something that is *not* an underscore and then an underscore.  It's generally like `[^X]`.

```perl
/^[^_]*_[^_]*_[^_]*$/

# or 

/^(?:[^_]*_){2}[^_]*$/
```

That is:
beginning of string
anything not an underscore
underscore
anything not an underscore
underscore
anything not an underscore
end of string

This is just one way to do it.

HTH

Comment: Nice, I guess in the documentation the difference between using "." and negating as you have done is made clear? FYI, final code used was terms[stringr::str_detect(terms, '^(?:[^_]*_){2}[^_]*$')]

Comment: @Nebulloyd     Well, `"."` is any char and `[^_]` any char except "_" ...., but I doubt the documentation focuses on the distinction except to say exactly that in two different places.

Comment: You had asked for a regex way to do it but counting the number of "_" is the "right way" to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Solution using the `stringr` package. It is a little more straight forward without having to use a complex `regular expression`. Here we are using the `str_count` function to count the number of matches in a string.

```r
terms<-c('breeding'
    ,'foraging'
    ,'prey'
    ,'breeding_season'
    ,'foraging_time'
    ,'seabird_ecology'
    ,'annual_reproductive_success'
    ,'sea_surface_temperature'
    ,'mean_chick_weight')

library(stringr)

terms[str_count(terms, "_") == 2]

#> [1] "annual_reproductive_success" "sea_surface_temperature"    
#> [3] "mean_chick_weight"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: also nice but I am sticking with str_detect for now because of my workflow

Comment: The counting function cannot distinguish whether there are intervening characters or whether there are leading non-underscores using that pattern so perhaps the pattern should be `"._"`

Comment: @IRTFM - can you please give an example so I can better understand how this solution isn't optimal for OP requirement of wanting to select all strings that have exactly two underscores ('_')?

Comment: Actually, I just wrote a comment to the question that attempted to clarify that point. I thought that the request was probably attempting to find 2 underscores separating meaningful text, but maybe I guessed wrong? My mind-reading is somewhat limited so I ask questions. I did say "perhaps".

Answer (score 2):

Here's why your efforts were failing:

```
"_{2}" #matches two underscores beside each other
"._.{2,}"  matches any char, "_", exactly 2 chars, "_", any char
```

Simplest (but not quite what you asked for) with `grepl` or `str_detect` would be:

```
 grepl("_.*_", terms)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

The "*" allows an arbitrary number of characters, so use negated charactyer class fore, aft and in the middle to get exactly 2 Underscores separating non underscores.:

```
  grepl("^[^_]_[^_]*_[^_]$", terms)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Added the "^" and the "$" to indicate the beginning and end. The "^" operator is different in meaning inside and outside of character-class brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep` with `value = TRUE` :

```
grep('^\\w+_\\w+_\\w+$', terms, value = TRUE)

#[1] "annual_reproductive_success" "sea_surface_temperature"    
#[3] "mean_chick_weight"
```

In `stringr` you can use `str_subset` with same regex :

```
stringr::str_subset(terms, '^\\w+_\\w+_\\w+$')
```